# how to call function

Tags: unity, c#

how do I get a function from another script and insert it into a button, I did this is giving this error

"Object reference not set to an instance of an object"

```
public Button Mybutton;

    void Indice(){
        if (index <= 0)
    {
        index = 0;
    }

    if (index >= 2)
    {
        index = 2;
    }

        if (index == 0)
    {
        Mybutton.GetComponent<Button>().GetComponent<MyScript>().MyFunction();
    }
    else if (index == 1)
    {
        Mybutton.GetComponent<Button>().GetComponent<MyScript>().MyFunction2();
    }
    else if (index == 2)
    {
        Mybutton.GetComponent<Button>().GetComponent<MyScript>().MyFunction3();
    }
```

Comment: `MyButton` is already of type `Button`, so `Mybutton.GetComponent<Button>()` is redundant. But if ultimately what you want is a `MyScript`, why not just make your variable `public MyScript myScriptInstance;` instead?

Comment: while to this I know, the business is to get this void and pass it to a button, is that I'm still learning

Answer (score 0):

There are some errors:

```
Mybutton.GetComponent<Button>().GetComponent<MyScript>().MyFunction();
```

1. MyButton is correctly referenced ?
2. If Yes, just use: MyButton.GetComponent().MyFunction();

To get MyButton reference use:

```
GameObject MyButton = GameObject.Find("MyButton");
```

Comment: continue the error, I added

public Scripty MyScript;
public Button MyButton;
MyButton.GetComponent<MyScript>().MyFunction();